# How to drill hole into thin plastic sheet?

Tags: drilling

Ok, don't know if such simple questions get asked here, but I have a plastic PP container and I'd like to drill a couple of 1/2 inch holes into it, both on the base and the wall. Was wondering how to do it and whether the thin material would be able to take it or crack.

Rectangle with slight slanting walls, something like this
[image]
https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/clear-reusable-container-13464112062.html

Haven't gotten to measuring its thickness, haven't purchased it yet, just thinking whether its a good idea.

Comment: Not enough info. How thin is thin? And what type of container? Rectangle? Rectangle with slanted walls? Round? Are you drilling into the round or slanted wall? Do you want to use a hand drill or a drill press? Normally you use tape and back support and materials thinner than ~1/4" can grab and lift and spin out of control so you use zero rake plastic drills. And that's with the benefit of a a drill press. You also pilot drill. If you want to drill into a curved or slant or use a hand drill things change.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a punch.

Comment: @DKNguyen rectangle with slight slanting walls, something like this...https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/clear-reusable-container-13464112062.html haven't gotten to measuring its thickness, haven't purchased it yet, just thinking whether its a good idea.

Comment: @blacksmith37 what kind of punch?

Comment: @DribbleNibble A leather punch would be easiest to obtain I think (the kind you hit with a hammer). Don't use a claw hammer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the most practical and easy solution. Take a metallic pipe of same OD, heat it up, run it through, file off the blunt edges.

Comment: Not very precise though - out of round etc

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, not much precise, but close enough to work with washers etc. Depends on application really.

Answer (score 1):

I drilled thin plastic by sandwiching it between two bits of sacrificial wood.

Drilled through fine, as the clamps held it all rigid.

Comment: Thanks, will think it through, maybe it would be the smarter way even with a step drill so the plastic doesn't crack.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. A step drill. Image source: [Handy Hardware](https://www.handyhardware.ie/BlueSpot-Tools-HSS-Step-Drill-4-22mm32050_p_62892.html).*

Step drills have the advantage that there is no spiral to snatch the part. As a result there is less danger when drilling sheet material as the sheet will not be pulled up onto the cutter. They also have the advantage that they start small and step up to the desired size.

Comment: Would the step drill work on a PP container like this nd wont cause it to crack? https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/clear-reusable-container-13464112062.html

Comment: Used one exactly like that on plastic - still cracked. Which is why I suggest the wood in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For what is basically tupperware with slanted walls, that I would manually drill your way up to 1/2" with a pin vise or something similar (pin vises don't usually get as large as 1/2"). It's difficult to provide rear support while also resting flat and perpendicular for slanted walls like that to use a powered drill and that is so thin and soft you don't need a power drill. With manual drilling just hold a wood block behind it with your hands as you twist the pin vise back and forth.

A punch and hammer would make cleaner edges if you can find one and have a narrow overhanging support (like the horn of an anvil) to provide rear support for the slanted wall and position it horizontally from the inside without needing the perfect shape to also support the far slanted wall against a table top.

Don't use a claw hammer. It's too hard and could shatter the punch or throw chips off the hammer and hurt yourself. Use a ball peen hammer, copper/bronze/aluminum mallet or something else. Not a hardened steel claw hammer